# Playing with Wordpress permalink htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have an website where I've installed Wordpress and enabled Permalinks with the following  .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]


AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript


RewriteRule ^sales$ dresses [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

As you can see in the above code, where ^sales gets redirected to the dresses page, according to my code. However, when I try to browse http://wordpressexample.com/sales, it is actually redirecting to the 404 page.

What could be the solution to mitigate this issue.

Comment: What is the url you get when you go to /sales? does it directly go to your 404 or is there a link in-between? I think your problem is with the dresses part, try changing it to the full link. something like wordpressexample.com/dress

Comment: When i go to /sales i get a 404 page, yes it directly goes to 404.
and when i enter the full link like wordpressexample.com/dress in the htaccess then what happens is when i enter wordpressexample.com/sales the page redirects to this wordpressexample.com/dress what i want to do is internal redirection...

Comment: Well your question was how to redirect to the dress page when typing in /sales. Anyways, Internal Rewrite you mean? Try this: RewriteRule "^/sales$" "/dress$" [NC, L]